# php open link with image in the same window

Tags: php, html, image, hyperlink, html-email

I am opening a link with an image, but I want to ensure that the link always opens in the same page, here is my code

```
echo  "<a href=\"/mysite.com/$directory/$dir/$line\"><img src=\"/mysite.com/images/000001.png\"  /></a>";
```

This works fine, but sometimes opens in a new page, i tried including target = "_self" but cannot get this to work

The link is sent in an email, so in some accounts, a pop window asks if the user wants to open or save, it is this I want to avoid and have the link open directly from the email which it does in gmail but not in hotmail

Comment: Side note - you know if you want to avoid all that horrendous escaping making the HTML barely readadble, you could just enclose the string in single quotes in PHP...

Comment: Anyway there's nothing here in the code which would control where the image opens...it should always open in the same tab, unless somehow there's a browser setting (which I admit I'm not aware of) which can affect it.

Comment: the link is sent in an email, so in some accounts, a pop window asks if the user wants to open or save, it is this I want to avoid and have the link open directly from the email which it does in gmail but not in hotmail

Comment: You should [edit] the question to mention that this is about HTML email and explain what you've said in your last comment, it's a very important detail and should not be hidden away down here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not something you can control. The HTML in the email is interpreted by the various email clients and they decide how links should be opened.

The Outlook Web App (used by Hotmail), automatically strips the `target` attribute on anchor elements and includes `target="_blank"` instead.